# How to make end-of-buffer move to the last line not beyond it?

Tags: evil, motion

I'm playing with evil-mode and this is one of the things where evil differs from vim. In vim `G` takes you to the last line, but evil uses Emacs `end-of-buffer` which for some reason takes me beyond last line to some imaginary line.

Comment: Emacs and Vim differ in how they deal with the final newline. Evil does *not* try working around this as it's purely concerned with emulating Vim-style editing. I've found it helpful to visualize it with fringe indicators, you may find another package of that kind useful.

Comment: I'm sorry, visualise what?

Comment: The final newline.

Comment: @wasamasa Hmm, I don't see the point of doing that. Can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `end-of-buffer` uses a variation on `(goto-char (point-max))` to go to the last position in the buffer. If the buffer ends with a newline, `end-of-buffer` will leave you on the empty line at the end, whereas if you delete this last newline, `end-of-buffer` will leave you at the end of the text in the now non-empty last line.

One possible solution is to advise `end-of-buffer` to just go up a line if it leaves you on an empty line:

```el
(defun my-end-of-buffer-dwim (&rest _)
  "If current line is empty, call `previous-line'."
  (when (looking-at-p "^$")
    (previous-line)))

(advice-add #'end-of-buffer :after #'my-end-of-buffer-dwim)
```

If you want `end-of-buffer` to always leave you at the *beginning* of the penultimate line (rather than at the end if the file has no trailing newline), you might want this instead:

```el
(defun my-end-of-buffer-dwim (&rest _)
  "Go to beginning of line.
If current line is empty, go to beginning of previous one
instead."
  (beginning-of-line (and (looking-at-p "^$") 0)))

(advice-add #'end-of-buffer :after #'my-end-of-buffer-dwim)
```

And the standard advice disclaimer: You can avoid unanticipated side-effects by just creating your own end-of-buffer command and rebinding the keys, rather than using advice:

```el
(defun my-end-of-buffer ()
  "Go to beginning of last line in buffer.
If last line is empty, go to beginning of penultimate one
instead."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (beginning-of-line (and (looking-at-p "^$") 0)))

(global-set-key [remap end-of-buffer] #'my-end-of-buffer)
```

Note that all of the above solutions leave you at most one line away from the end of the buffer - they do not leave you on the *last* non-empty line.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works! I'm new to elisp, so I haven't knew about `advice-add`. I didn't want to remap keys, because in evil `G` is a motion, so you can delete till the end of file with `dG` etc. I don't think tht.his would work if I would just remap key to another function. But maybe I don't know lisp well enough.

Comment: If you wish to remap ```my-end-of-buffer``` to the default shortcut (overriding it), use ```(global-set-key "\M->" #'my-end-of-buffer)```.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't answer your question, [question about stopping Emacs scrolling past end-of-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675772/keep-emacs-from-scrolling-past-end-of-buffer.).

```
(setq next-line-add-newlines t)
```

The problem with this though is that mouse scroll is not going paste end-of-buffer, and you will end up with alot of empty lines in your files (pressing down arrows adds newlines, up arrow does not remove them).

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't answer my question